# Hyper-V - wide screen resolutions?

Tags: windows-8, hyper-v

I've created Windows 7 virtual machine on Windows 8 Hyper-V, but can find how to set resolution to anything widescreen (my monitor supports 1920x1200) to be able work fullscreen.
Is it possible to get any widescreen resolution on Hyper-V virtual machine?

Comment: What happens if you fullscreen the Window (Alt-Enter)?  How have you been trying to set the resolution so far?

Comment: going fullscreen doesn't help. stays 4:3.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this:

1. Change the resolutions within the remote OS
2. If connecting to a Windows OS, connect using Remote Desktop Connection instead of Hyper-V Viewer.

   Using RDP allows for more functionality including Client Screen Size, Audio, and Remote USB integration.

Comment: In resolution list on remote OS (Win7) I can't find any widescreen resolutions, they all are 4:3

Comment: RDP supports all resolutions that I need, but performance is terrible - I can see how my desktop is redrawing :(

Answer (score 5):

For the moment, the answer seems to be a resounding "you can't do that."

The Hyper-V virtual video card is an 8MB card that only supports the 4:3 resolutions you see in the video control panel.

These are the options I've looked at:

1. Remote Desktop: This is the only choice if you want to stick with Hyper-V
2. VMWare Player or Workstation: VMWare Workstation isn't free, but it offers very good display support, including 3D acceleration. It also dynamically resizes the display resolution based on your window size. (Drag the window and the resolution changes automatically to fit the window.)
3. Virtualbox: free and open source

In the end, I chose to simply RDP in to my virtual machine. It's the simplest method that fits my needs.

Comment: If the guest OS is Windows 10, I can set it to any resolution by simple resizing the "Virtual Machine Connection" windows. Why does this not work with Windows 7?

Comment: Apparently Windows 7 guest OS does not support all features of Hyper-V, one being setting more screen resolutions (another being copy/paste not working).