# Windows 8.1 Professional Hyper-V - can I create my own linux VM through it?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, hyper-v, windows-8.1

I have a Windows 8.1 Professional desktop, and would like to have a Linux Mint VM on it so I can do some opensource web development work.  I've tried VirtualBox, but it's giving me an IO error during the Mint .iso installation.  VMWare Player flat out tells me it can't install because I have Hyper-V on my machine by default.

My biggest concern is nuking the desktop, which is where I do most of my non-development work/browsing/etc.  The desktop seems to be listed as a VM itself in the Hyper-V Manager, and I don't want to accidentally break it.

So, two questions:

1. Can I create the Mint VM I want/need for my work?
2. Can I do it without messing up the desktop?

Comment: Are you tied to Mint? Would you be willing to switch to one of the Linux distributions on the [Supported Guest OS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794868%28WS.10%29.aspx) list? You never mention trying to create a VM for Mint in Hyper-V, or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just go and do it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I prefer Mint to something like Ubuntu because of its UI.  The other distros are too fiddly for my tastes.  I want something easy to use and (mostly) idiot proof so I can just install the packages I need and start developing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing your computer is listed as a server/host and not a VM.

The only notable difference I can think of is that you'll have virtual network adapters after enabling Hyper-V. Your computer's and VM's adapters will all be in Network Connections as virtual adapters.

If you ever disable Hyper-V this will be rolled back to how it normally is.

If I remember correctly, in Windows 8 at least, Mint will default back to the 2D UI, so no 3D acceleration if you are developing for that. In my experience it did this for VirtualBox as well.

Comment: Is there a way to tell it to use my native resolution, or to turn on 3D acceleration?  Right now it's defaulting to a 4:3 display.

Comment: @KevinM1 Sorry, I can't remember. [Here's a similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/496434/hyper-v-wide-screen-resolutions).

Comment: @KevinM1 Unfortunately Microsoft only supports 3D acceleration on modern windows platforms when you install the integration software. I VMware is the only provider I know of who has 3D support in Linux.